# Maclaurin series construction

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I am asked to find the Taylor (Maclaurin) series for $9xe^x$ at $x=0$.

I did the following:

$f(x)=9xe^x \implies f'(x)=9e^x(1+x) \implies f''(x)=9e^x(2+x)$ et cetera. This yields:

$P_0(x)=0, P_1(x)=\frac{9}{1!}x, P_2(x)=\frac{2*9}{2!}x^2$ et cetera. So then I made the series:

$\large \Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(9n)x^n}{n!}$. What am I doing wrong? Where is my logic failing?

I know what the solution is and the answer, but I would like to know why my logic is not correct. Even my terms are wrong.

The solution:

$e^x=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \implies 9xe^x=9\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}$

Comment: Do a change of index.

Comment: @DavidMitra, already done in the last line.

Comment: Your expression is OK. Needs a little simplification.

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla I am sorry, I just started out with series and I am not really understanding what to do. By change of index, do you mean that I should add the series of e^x to the series of 9x?

Comment: Just take the series of $e^x$ and multiply the result by $9x$.

Comment: @Akitirija, take the second series and do $m=n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing, really. You're not using the fastest, least-work, solution, but that doesn't make yours wrong in any way.

Well, provided your "et cetera" contains a proof, by induction or otherwise, of

$$f^{(n)}(x) = 9e^x(n+x).$$

If you merely spotted a pattern and concluded that it will continue without being able to say *why* it continues [and a correct explanation of that is easily transformable into a proof, if it is not yet one], that would be a mistake.

> Even my terms are wrong.

No, they are correct, just not simplified as much as one could. You have

$$9xe^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(9n)x^n}{n!}.$$

We can pull the constant factor $9$ of each term out of the series to obtain

$$9\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n!}.$$

Next we observe that the term for $n = 0$ is $0$, so we can drop that from the series and get

$$9\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n!}.$$

Then we recall that for $n \geqslant 1$ we have $n! = n\cdot (n-1)!$, and hence

$$9xe^x = 9\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n\cdot (n-1)!} = 9\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}.$$

Finally, we can shift the index of summation, call $n = m+1$, to get

$$9xe^x = 9\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{m+1}}{m!},$$

rename the summation index from $m$ to $n$, and lo-and-behold:

$$9xe^x = 9\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your amazing explanation. Now I understood it fully! Thank you for taking the time, Daniel!